# document expired after pressing back button

Tags: php

I have a page called a.php . It has a form and submit data via POST to same file (a.php) . Page loads with no error. Then I click any link (b.php or b.html) on that page . it directs to any page as usual. Then when I click back button from b.php or b.html it does not show previous page.

Any help to solve this matter ?

Thanks

Comment: U need to resubmit ur value

Comment: Can you explain little bit more?

Thanks

Comment: Please add your code for a.php it will help us to give you solution

Comment: This is an expected browser behaviour as you sent before POST values to the page you want to go back to. This behaviour cannot be explicitely removed. You can only workaround it by submitting the values via AJAX to a script which saves them into session and then Javascript takes the user to the new page where you read the POST values from the session. This way you don't send POST values directly to the page and therefore the browser won't show document expired if you go back.

Comment: @Charlotte  I will try this ajax method

thanks

Comment: Yes I can expain it :)

Answer (score 1):

**About Method**

The `$_POST` Method used for **SUBMITTING FORMS** something Create or Modify it is a secure method.In other words `POST` is sending data to server from browser

**FOR EXAMPLE**

- Creating Articles
- Editing Articles
- File Uploading

In your case you are getting values `POST` is not for getting values Use `$_GET` method for this

**Why Document Expires ?**

I taken this Image from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).

[image]

**Why Browser Do this?**

It is because it prevent from duplicate submission.

**For Example :**  On any shopping site there are payment options user buy a product and pay for it , now if he/she(user) refresh page again the payment done two times .

Comment: A couple of minor technicalities: POST is inherently no more secure than GET unless under a secure shell (https), it's just obfuscated. File uploads *should* be handled by PUT requests (if you're creating a new resource on the server) but that's not really supported/relevant with web-apps.

Answer (score 0):

according to your question, page a.php is submitting data (post) to the page itself, so if you go to other page and then want to back again to page a.php (by clicking the back button on browser) it causes document expired because when you click it you are not submitting any data (post) to page a.php.

Comment: I got your point.

But let's say in facebook,

you post an status update on home.php and it post data it self , may be I'm wrong

then we can press profile.php link from home.php, again press back button from profile.php .
But home.php is still there and we don't post data again.

Please correct me If I'm wrong

Thanks

Comment: facebook doing post data by using ajax, so it will handle them. just try to post data using ajax. you can see this one [http://www.formget.com/submit-form-using-ajax-php-and-jquery/](http://www.formget.com/submit-form-using-ajax-php-and-jquery/)

Comment: Thanks. I will try this method