# Let history.back() ignore Confirm Form Resubmission

Tags: javascript, php

In my web application all my form submissions goes to a action folder and then when its done it redirects the user where he was.
But my problem is after the user did something that requires the application to use the action folder and the process id done, when he presses the back button he gets this error

[image]

is there a way to "fix" this

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36644176/document-expired-after-pressing-back-button/36646160#36646160

Comment: If your processing scripts output nothing to the screen and simply 302 redirect they'll not be cached by the browser and won't appear in the `history` list - so they'd be skipped by `history.back()` and you'd avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

you can disable the back button functionality to avoid this error...
This code my help you.

```
<script type = "text/javascript" > 
    function preventBack(){window.history.forward();} 
    setTimeout("preventBack()", 0); 
    window.onunload=function(){null}; 
 </script>
```

Put this code where you don't want to go back...